# Rule to filter calendar invites with certain people in them

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I get invited to important meetings which I'd like to categorize as red to give them high visibility in my calendar. Sometimes it is a direct invite to me with those people in CC and sometimes it is a forwarded email.

Is there a way to create a rule for this in outlook (online or MacOS)?

Comment: What have you tried yet and where in the process did you get stuck?

Comment: I can categorise an invite but cannot filter it by certain people being also in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Update:***

Rule:

[image]

---

You can easily create a rule in Outlook web mail via **Settings>Mail>Rules>Add new rule**, as shown in the below figure:

[image]